# onActivityResult Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a list with all the applications installed in the phone. At the click on one of these part to uninstall the selected application. The problem is that even if the application was uninstalled, remains in the list. To remove it I have done this code but does not work (crash)

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    int requestCode = 1;
    app = appList.get(position);
    Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:" + app.packagename);
    this.position = position;
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
    startActivityForResult(uninstallIntent, requestCode);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        try {
            ApplicationInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(app.packagename, 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            appInfoArrayList.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the logcat

```
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.packagename/com.packagename.class}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3495)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3538)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:153)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at com.packagename.onActivityResult(myclass:java:87)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3491)
11-12 17:51:07.188: E/AndroidRuntime(27943):    ... 11 more
```

My intent is to remove the application from the list once it has been uninstalled but why crash and how to solve it?

Comment: probably your appInfoArrayList or adapter are null. What is onActivityResult(myclass:java:87)?

Comment: The data in onActivityResult is null,So kindly do research on why it retuns null.

Comment: Line 87 is adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Where do you instantiate the adapter?

Comment: So your adapter is null. Share where do you initialized it.